# What does __attribute__ ((aligned(x))) do?

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

NONE of the existing answer to that question made anything clearer for me. I don't know what it's supposed to mean when a variable is declared "within the boundary of x bytes", which is the answer given in every question regarding this. I need an actual explanation with example of what it is, and what it does compared to variables declared without that attribute, and why it should be used.

Bonus question: When used in front of an array like here `__attribute__ ((aligned (32))) double output[4];`, does that mean every single element of the array is aligned, or just the array as a whole?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `__attribute__ ` isn't a C++ keyword. It is probably a feature of the compiler you are using. You should specify your compiler otherwise answers will be based on guess work.

Comment: see e.g. http://www.songho.ca/misc/alignment/dataalign.html about what alignment is

Comment: "*I need an actual explanation with example of what it is*" Do you know what a "byte" is? Do you know what a byte "boundary" would be?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `__attribute__` in the C++ language. `__attribute__` is a language extension of GCC and compatible compilers.

`__attribute__ ((aligned (X)))` is essentially same as the standard `alignas` specifier:

```
// non-standard
__attribute__ ((aligned (32))) double output[4];

// standard
alignas(32) double output[4];
```

---

Every object has a memory address that designates the location of the byte in memory where the object is stored. The underlying representation of the address is an integer number. A memory address is **aligned** to X bytes when the number of the address is divisible by X.

Every type has a minimum requirement for the alignment of the address where an object of that type can be stored. `alignas` can be used to increase the requirement.

> When used in front of an array ... does that mean every single element of the array is aligned, or just the array as a whole?

The array as a whole is aligned. Not individual elements